# How can I increase disk size Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, disk-space

how to increase / from sbd?
help[image: df -h]

Comment: Your easiest option will most likely be to move the Home directory (/home) to it's own/seperate partition on sbd - assuming its presently under root. If not look at moving some other dir's like /opt, /temp, etc... Duck Duck Go is your friend! :-)

Comment: Phew, 4 GiB is really small! Please provide the outputs of `fdisk -l` and `vgs`. Please provide text as text, not as images. Format it as code to preserve whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to buy and connect a 2nd hard drive.  If that is not enough get a 3rd or 4th hard drive.

After that format it with a file system.
Then you could move all of say the home directory to the new drive sdb.

Then you could modify the fstab and mtab to automatically mount sdb as the home directory.

Of course your not limited to the home directory you could virtually ANY directory to the new hard drive(s).